# How to change the State when a Task is reassigned

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010, when we reassign a task with a state of "in process" back to someone else, we want the state to change back to "active" with a reason of "reassigned".

I'm pretty familiar with the Process Editor and have been able to muddle my way through customizing workflows and fields, but I'm not a coder by any means so I'm looking for a "dummies guide to automating state changes" approach.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

an alternate approach would be to write a tfsplugin that catches the workItemChanged event, and then alter the state when the reassigning happens.

see: http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/

You can either create a Server side plugin with ISubscribe or you can handle a SOAP event separately with TFS on-premises. If you are using VSO you can use Service Hooks.